What's the gain in this common gate amplifier?
Consider the circuit in this netlist. Assume all transistors are operating in saturation, \$V_{Tn} = │V_{Tp}│=VT\$,
\$\lambda ≠ 0\$ but \$\gamma = 0\$ (neglect body effect). Neglect all parasitic capacitances and consider only the two
capacitances \$C_{L1}\$ and \$C_{L2}\$.
Find the transfer function expressed in related circuit parameters and identify DC voltage gain and  the poles of the circuit.

The following  is my analysis:
To find the transfer function \$ \frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}} \$ of the two-stage CMOS amplifier and identify the DC voltage gain and poles, we proceed step by step:
First Stage Analysis:

Node \$ V_x \$: The small-signal voltage \$ v_s \$ at the source of \$ M_{n1} \$.

Current through \$ R_S \$: \$ \frac{v_{\text{in}} - v_s}{R_S} \$.

Drain currents:
$$
  i_{d_{n1}} = -g_{m_{n1}} v_s + \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}}
  $$
$$
  i_{d_{p1}} = \frac{v_{D1}}{r_{o_{p1}}}
  $$

KCL at Node \$ D1 \$:
$$
  -g_{m_{n1}} v_s + \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}} + \frac{v_{D1}}{r_{o_{p1}}} + j\omega C_{L1} v_{D1} = 0
  $$

KCL at Node \$ V_x \$:
$$
  \frac{v_{\text{in}} - v_s}{R_S} = g_{m_{n1}} v_s - \frac{v_{D1} - v_s}{r_{o_{n1}}}
  $$


Assume \$r_{o_{n1}} g_{m_{n1}} \gg 1 \$, \$r_{o_{n1}} = r_{o_{p1}} \$
After simplification, first stage DC gain will be the following
$$A_{v1} = \frac{V_{D1}} {V_{in}} \approx \frac{r_{o_{n1}} g_{m_{n1}}} { 2 + R_S g_{m_{n1}} } $$
However, the answer from my teacher give the following answer.
First stage DC gain:
$$\mid G_{m,eff} \mid = \frac{g_{m_{n1}}} {1 + g_{m_{n1}} R_S}$$
$$R_{out,eff} = \biggl( r_{o_{n1}} (1 + g_{m_{n1}} R_S) \biggl) \parallel r_{o_{p1}} $$
$$A_{v1} = \mid G_{m,eff} \mid R_{out,eff} =  \frac{g_{m_{n1}}} {1 + g_{m_{n1}} R_S} \biggl( r_{o_{n1}} (1 + g_{m_{n1}} R_S) \biggl) \parallel r_{o_{p1}} $$
